# react-router-dom return undefined when second history.push is triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi have the following Antd modal:

```
<Modal visible={visible} onOk={handleOk} onCancel={handleCancel}>
  <MyForm onSubmit={handleOpenUrl}>
      <CustomInput
        name="input"
        onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
          handleInput(event, "input")
        }
      />
      <Button type="submit" >
        Submit
      </Button>
  </MyForm>
</Modal>;
```

And I have the following handler for this form:

```
const handleInput = (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // other operation where checked is handled...
  history.push({
    pathname: "/",
    search: "?" + new URLSearchParams({ datas: checked }).toString(),
  });
};
```

the weird thing is that when I open the form and I submit the form for the first time it update the url and add it like the following: `http://localhost:3000/?datas=myqueryparams` but when I do it for the second time it says: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`

Any ideas about that?

**UPDATE**

for app component I have added the following:

```
<Switch>
          <Route path="/?datas=:datas" exact component={App} />
          <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
        </Switch>
```

Comment: We need more context. Where is the `history object coming from? How does this component relate to any routing context provider? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This history object is coming from the useHistory hook provided by react-router-dom

Comment: Can you update your question to include all the relevant code? The entire component code using the `useHistory` hook, and where you are providing a routing context to your app via a router component?

Answer (score -1):

have you wrapped the app component with `BrowserRouter` from react-router-dom ?
example code like this

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
     <ChildComponent />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Questions asking for clarification should be made as comments.

Comment: I have made an update, check it out